# Using Integrated Webcam of a laptop as camera in Android SDKVersion 16

Tags: android, camera

I've been looking into getting a live camera preview working in the Android emulator. Currently the Android emulator just gives a black and white chess board animation. After having a look around I found the web site of Tom Gibara who has done some great work to get a live preview working in the emulator.

The real problem is that I cannot get the WebcamBroadcaster.java running since when I compile it with jMyron I get the following errors.:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\processing\processing\lib\JMyron\library\JMyron.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at JMyron.JMyron.(JMyron.java:14)
    at jopc.WebcamBroadcaster.start(WebcamBroadcaster.java:84)
    at jopc.WebcamBroadcaster.main(WebcamBroadcaster.java:44)

I have foolowed all the installation steps of JMyron including copying the two native dll files to Windows/SysWoW64 directory as I am running a 64 bit Win 7.
I did a lot of googling but did not find any solutions to this, hence I am here.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance